# can I indent code in Visual Studio Code without extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been trying for a few hours now to add AutoHotKey for Visual Studio Code.

Can I indent a file (like html code) in **visual studio code** without any extensions?
Some extensions like **beautify** work current. But I want to do this without any extensions.
Thanks

Comment: Indent how? VS Code has a default formatter that should indent your HTML code. Your indentation settings are also visible on the bottom right of your status bar.

Comment: Isn't standard shortcut working for you?
ctrl+K and ctrl+D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by selecting the correct language mode and using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.